# vb.net adding non constans font styles to richtextbox selection

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

Is there a better way to build FontStyle with with "add/append" approach instead of listing all possible combinations?

```
'l is an instance of class that holds bold/italic/underline as booleans

Dim fStyle As New FontStyle
If l.fontBold And Not l.fontItalic And Not l.fontUnderline Then
    fStyle = FontStyle.Bold
ElseIf Not l.fontBold And l.fontItalic And Not l.fontUnderline Then
    fStyle = FontStyle.Italic
ElseIf Not l.fontBold And Not l.fontItalic And l.fontUnderline Then
    fStyle = FontStyle.Underline
ElseIf l.fontBold And l.fontItalic And Not l.fontUnderline Then
    fStyle = FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic
ElseIf l.fontBold And Not l.fontItalic And l.fontUnderline Then
    fStyle = FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Underline
ElseIf Not l.fontBold And l.fontItalic And l.fontUnderline Then
    fStyle = FontStyle.Italic Or FontStyle.Underline
ElseIf l.fontBold And l.fontItalic And l.fontUnderline Then
    fStyle = FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic Or FontStyle.Underline
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The `FontStyle` enum has a `FlagsAttribute`, what means that you can combine enum constants with `Or`.

```
<Flags>
Public Enum FontStyle
```

Do it like this

```
Dim fStyle As FontStyle = FontStyle.Regular

If l.fontBold
    fStyle = fStyle Or FontStyle.Bold
End If
If l.fontItalic
    fStyle = fStyle Or FontStyle.Italic
End If
If l.fontUnderline
    fStyle = fStyle Or FontStyle.Underline
End If
```

See: [Use Enumerated Values with Bit Flags to Handle Multiple Options](http://www1.visualstudiomagazine.com/Blogs/Tool-Tracker/2013/05/Enumerated-Values-with-Bit-Flags.aspx)